# How to use Sync adapter to transfer data with server?

Tags: android, android-syncadapter

I am completely new to android sync adapter concept & seeking some good resources to understand how does it really transfer data with server.

Below are couple of links, I found out but unable to understand part of data transfer with server/backend. Moreover, I am looking forward for combined material instead of individual.

http://blog.udinic.com/2013/07/24/write-your-own-android-sync-adapter/
http://www.androidtutorialsworld.com/sync-adapter-example-android/
http://chariotsolutions.com/blog/post/android-data-sync/
https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html
https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/index.html

Last 2 are quite high level for me to understand.